# Python 3.6 not found as a choice of applications in Ubuntu 18.04 properties

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, python3, properties

Despite extensive research, trial-n-error, uninstalling and re-installing, I can not get any of my python scripts to run from other than a terminal command line. The scripts once had the python icon, but now, even they are gone. I have not been able to associate them with python from the association pulldown choices in properties. The several suggestions thus far have been fruitless. I ensure the scripts are made executable and the shebang line is /usr/bin/python3. Still nothing works. Any help to remedy this situation would be greatly appreciated.